# print css only fails in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have the following print css:

```
@media print {
body > * {
    display: none;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFF;
}

.print-div{
    display: block !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in Safari. Safari print review would only display a blank page.

I tried to set body with 'visibility:hidden' and print-div with 'visibility:visible', the div shows up, but the body would have too many pages, and I only want to print on one single page with my print-div.

Why is display failing in Safari?

Comment: did you give the 100% height also to html? (height, not width, I wrote this wrong before)

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for your comment! And yes, but that didn't work either. I tried setting all my print div's position to static or relative and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For those who encounter similar issues, I tried to set my print div `position:static` to print. No idea why, but it works.